# Removing a CSS rule from Custom Taxonomy

Tags: css

I have a universal CSS rule in my stylesheet like this:

```
#page.grid-parent {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px
}
```

What I'd like to do is REMOVE that rule from some Custom Taxonomy Archive Pages I have.

So, if I look at the **body** tag of an example page I see this:

```
<body class="archive tax-country term-saudi-arabia term-445 wp-custom-logo wp-embed-responsive cookies-set cookies-accepted post-image-below-header post-image-aligned-center no-sidebar nav-float-right fluid-header separate-containers active-footer-widgets-0 header-aligned-left dropdown-hover elementor-default" itemtype="https://schema.org/Blog" itemscope>
```

I am sure that I can use the "tax-country" as the hook to hide that CSS rule.

To hide the CSS rule from those pages I tried this:

```
#page.grid-parent.tax-country {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px
}
```

....and it didn't work...

I also tried to use the #tax-country ID like this:

```
#tax-country.grid-parent {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

And still no joy...

Comment: How about `body.tax-country #page.grid-parent` ? But CSS questions like this is better asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this below CSS. I think, It will work.

```
.tax-country #page.grid-parent {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px
}
```